# Unable to install apple swift-format using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

Unable to run apple swift-format, as it fails with the following error:

```bash
brew install swift-format
swift-format 
dyld[20113]: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/0.50600.1/bin/swift-format
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/0.50600.1/bin/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.5/macosx/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/0.50600.1/bin/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.5/macosx/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I was running OSX 13.3 (Ventura) and Xcode 14.2. Like you I also installed `swift-format` via Homebrew.

The error is actually pretty helpful in this case

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/0.50600.1/bin/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib
```

That executable is missing from the bin folder. In order to fix this you should:

1. Download [Swift Format](https://github.com/apple/swift-format/releases). You can use the latest or match the version Homebrew installed.
2. Open a terminal window in the downloaded swift format folder.
3. Run `swift build -c release` which will compile swift format and create the executables.
4. Copy the swift format executable from `./build/release/swift-format` (the build folder is hidden by default, but it will appear in the downloaded directory once you build).
5. Paste swift format executable in `/usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/0.50600.1/bin/` (You will replace the existing one)
6. Copy `lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib` from `./build/release/`
7. Paste `lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib` in `/usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/0.50600.1/bin/`

**Note** - You can access `/usr/local` or `/opt/homebrew` by accessing your hard drive directly in Finder.

**Note** - This will work for any version you just have to change the homebrew location `/usr/local/Cellar/swift-format/MY_VERSION_HERE/bin/`

There might be an "easier" way to solve this, but if you copy the missing file to one of the paths swift format checks (and the library version and swift format version match) this will work.

Comment: Great!, it worked but now you will only get swift-format executable and not lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib

Comment: @CreekyCrap not sure I understand. Without `lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib` you would still have the original issue since that's what was missing.

Comment: As per readme doc on [Swift Format](https://github.com/apple/swift-format) `As of Swift 5.8, swift-format depends on the version of SwiftSyntax whose parser has been rewritten in Swift and no longer has dependencies on libraries in the Swift toolchain.

This change allows swift-format to be built, developed, and run using any version of Swift that can compile it, decoupling it from the version that supported a particular syntax. However, earlier versions of swift-format will still not be able to recognize new syntax added in later versions of the language and parser.`